# SQL Server - How to get the minimum and maximum datetime for each day grouped against name and location

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting

Using our door access system data, we have been asked to provide the earliest and latest time each day that someone scans a card for each building. This data needs to include the staff name.

Basically, the first in and the last out of each building every day.

For example:

```
+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
|        Scantime         |    Staff     |  Building  |
+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
| 2018-06-01 05:13:27.000 | Joe Bloggs   | Building 1 |
| 2018-06-01 05:30:19.000 | Mary Sue     | Building 2 |
| 2018-06-01 05:42:44.000 | Pete Generic | Building 3 |
| 2018-06-01 05:47:46.000 | Pete Generic | Building 4 |
| 2018-06-01 16:30:35.000 | Joe Bloggs   | Building 1 |
| 2018-06-01 16:46:49.000 | John Generic | Building 2 |
| 2018-06-01 16:58:11.000 | Joe Bloggs   | Building 4 |
| 2018-06-01 17:14:15.000 | Joe Bloggs   | Building 3 |
+-------------------------+--------------+------------+
```

We've had some success with the following query:

```
SELECT       ScanTime, Staff, Building
FROM            dbo.SentryJuno$ AS t1
WHERE        (ScanTime IN
                             (SELECT        MIN(ScanTime) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.SentryJuno$
                               GROUP BY CONVERT(date, TimeStamp), Building)) OR
                         (ScanTime IN
                             (SELECT        MAX(ScanTime) AS Expr1
                               FROM            dbo.SentryJuno$ AS SentryJuno$_1
                               GROUP BY CONVERT(date, ScanTime), Building))
```

The issue with this query being that if there are any identical timestamps/scantimes in the data, it returns both.

Is there anyway we could improve the accuracy of this query?

Comment: Why not just min and max and group by name and building?

Comment: Can you please provide expected result? Im a bit confused about how you want your results.

Comment: The first table is the expected output, it has the earliest time for each building and the member of staff and then the latest.

Comment: Ahh okay, then i misunderstood it :) Then union it like WhatsThePoint writes

Comment: the issue of identical timestamps (for a particular building I presume) - you need to decide what you would want to do, the simplest solution is a tie breaker, even a random one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Staff, Building, 
CAST(ScanTime AS DATE) AS ScanDate, 
MIN(ScanTime) AS FirstScanTime,
MAX(ScanTime) AS LastScanTime
FROM dbo.[SentryJuno$]
GROUP BY Staff, Building, CAST(ScanTime AS DATE);
```

Or looking into your query maybe you are asking for:

```
SELECT Staff, Building, 
CAST(ScanTime AS DATE) AS ScanDate, 
MIN(ScanTime) AS ScanTime
FROM dbo.[SentryJuno$]
GROUP BY Staff, Building, CAST(ScanTime AS DATE)
UNION 
SELECT Staff, Building, 
CAST(ScanTime AS DATE) AS ScanDate, 
MAX(ScanTime) AS ScanTime
FROM dbo.[SentryJuno$]
GROUP BY Staff, Building, CAST(ScanTime AS DATE)
```

EDIT: Your question is not clear, reading comments maybe you are asking for this?:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.SentryJuno$ s
     INNER JOIN(
               SELECT Building, CAST(Scantime AS DATE) AS ScanDate, MIN(Scantime) AS ScanTime
               FROM dbo.SentryJuno$
               GROUP BY Building, CAST(Scantime AS DATE)
               UNION
               SELECT Building, CAST(Scantime AS DATE) AS ScanDate, MAX(Scantime) AS ScanTime
               FROM dbo.SentryJuno$
               GROUP BY Building, CAST(Scantime AS DATE)
               ) fl ON fl.Building=s.Building
                  AND fl.ScanTime=s.Scantime;
```

Comment: I've edited the question to hopefully make it a bit clearer, it's basically a first in and last out each day for each building.

Comment: Then the last query is that.

Comment: This seems to work more reliably than our one, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as(
            SELECT t1.Scantime, 
                t1.Staff, 
                t1.Building, 
                row_number() over (PARTITION BY CAST(t1.Scantime AS DATE), t1.Building ORDER BY t1.Scantime ASC) RNF,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY CAST(t1.Scantime AS DATE), t1.Building ORDER BY t1.Scantime DESC) RNL
            FROM dbo.SentryJuno$ AS t1
            )
SELECT DQ.Scantime,DQ.staff, DQ.Building (select * from CTE where CTE.RNF = 1 UNION select * from CTE where CTE.RNL = 1) DQ
    ORDER BY DQ.Scantime
```